# How to use WebDriver "waitFor" method?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am slightly unsure as how to use the "waitFor" method supplied with WebDriver,
see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wd

Say I have a boolean value, I want to wait until this value becomes true.
How can I do this using "waitFor"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the examples in the link below can help you:
https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/examples/promise/wait-for-simple.js
https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/examples/promise/wait-for-custom.js

Answer (score 0):

In java it would go something like this:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, interval);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() { 
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        boolean value = <some condition>
                        if (value) {
                            return true;
                        } else
                            return false;
                    }
     });
```

Not sure which language you are using, but it shouldn't be a problem to translate it, logic is the same.